# GitLab backup auto-cleanup

Tags: cron, backup, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

So I have GitLab installed on our server and I also followed [their guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html) on how to setup the backups.

#### Goal

1. [[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#configuring-cron-to-make-daily-backups)] Create a `cron` task to backup the data every Tuesday - Saturday at 2:00 AM
2. [[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#uploading-to-locally-mounted-shares)] Upload the created backup file to a Windows mounted drive
3. [[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#configuring-cron-to-make-daily-backups)] Remove backup files older than 2 weeks (14 days) on both the local server and the Windows mounted drive

So far only 2½ of my goals are achieved.

For `#3`, setting `gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 1209600` only cleans up the files on the local server but not the uploaded files on the mounted Windows drive.

What do I need to do so that GitLab cleans both backup locations?

---

#### Additional Info

I have used the GitLab CE Omnibus installation.
Currently our version is `GitLab CE 9.1.2 df1403f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer where GitLab will take care of this for me so I just created another `cron` task:

```
0 3 * * * find /path/to/mounted/drive/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*_gitlab_backup.tar" -mtime +13 -delete
```